# Continuity of distribution function

Tags: continuity

Given $$F(x)= \begin{cases} 0 &x<0\\
             x &0\leq x\leq1\\
             1 &x>1\end{cases}$$

Why this distribution function is discontinuous at $x=0$ and $x=1$

But according to me 
$F(1)=1$ and $$\lim(1-h)=1 F(1+)=1$$
and similarly for $0$

Then how can we say that it is discontinuous at $x=0$ and $x= 1$

---

Comment: $F$ is continuous at all points.

Comment: The $F$ you give is a cdf, not a pdf. **It is continuous everywhere**. Its associated pdf (its derivative) $f$ is not even defined in $x=0$ and $x=1$ (characteristic fonction of interval $[0,1]$).

Comment: This is a CDF, a cumulative distribution function. This function is continuous everywhere as you have seen. However, the CDF has an associated density which cannot be defined at $0$ and $1$ but can be done everywhere else. If you like, I can write an answer for this question.